# How to convert a time (char) variable into a numeric variable?

Tags: sas, type-conversion

I have a time variable that is expressed as a character in SAS. Example: 0:04 0:12 0:01 0:11 etc. I would like to convert it to a numeric variable 0.04 0.12 0.01 etc.
Using this code:

```
data work.set2; set work.set;
TIME2 = input(TIME, best4.);
;
run;
```

creates a new column with nothing but missing values. Can you advice on what to improve in my code?

Comment: What would that mean?  `'0:10'` looks like 10 seconds to me. If you convert that to the number `0.1` what would it mean?  If that number is in minutes then 0.1 would mean 6 seconds instead of 10 seconds.

Comment: @tom I want to transform it into a numerical variable because I want to run a regression and understand what impact the incremental change will have. So converting it either to 0.1 or 10 seconds would not affect the interpretation I hope.

Answer (score 1):

SAS stores dates and times as numbers, time is the number of seconds. I think converting it to a SAS time is your best option. And there is a significant difference between 0.1 and 10 seconds because one is 6 seconds and one is 10 seconds. For example if you had 0.1 and 0.2 and took the difference that's 0.1 -> is that now a 10 or 6 second difference. You really need to think this through on how you want to interpret it and using your approach will be problematic.
The difference in times will not be reflected correctly.

Also, is 0:04 4 seconds or 4 minutes. The standard connotation would be 4 minutes, which is 240 seconds.

Here's how you can convert it:

```
data have;

x = '0:04';output;
x = '0:12';output;
x = '0:11'; output;
x = '1:00'; output;
x = '4:25'; output;

run;

data want;
set have;

sas_time = input(x, time.);
sas_time2 = sas_time;
format sas_time2 time4.;


/*if it's seconds*/
seconds = input(scan(x, 1, ':'), 8.)*60 + input(scan(x, 2, ':'), 8.);

run;

proc print data=want;run;
```

Comment: the seconds=...... statement worked! The first part of your code does exactly what you explained above 0:04 is converted into 240 seconds. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can also prefix your strings with '00:' and then the TIME informat will interpret them as seconds instead of minutes.  `seconds=input('00:'||x,time.);`

Answer (score -1):

If your times are of type string:

```
WITHDOTS=translate(TIME2,'.',':');
```

Source:
https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Find-And-Replace-within-a-string/td-p/45104

Comment: I just ran the code and it just duplicated the time column with the variables in the same format. 0:04 -> 0:04 data work.set2; set work.set;
TIME2=translate(TIME,':','.');
run;

Comment: TRANSLATE is a string function, this will not give the desired results.

Comment: The arguments are backwards. Syntax is `translate(string,tochars,fromchars)`.

Comment: @Reeza Thanks for the info. The type of variables wasn't clear to me. I'll leave it standing here for anyone who might have their times in a string. Updated answer to make this clear as well.